# C++ Programming major help needed LINKED LISTS I just can't see where my error is although it is running

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct list
{
  char name[20];
  int age;
  double height;
  list *next;
};

list *first = NULL, *current;
int optn = 0;

void currentfor()
{
  if (current->next == NULL)
    cout << "List has ended!" << endl;
  else
    current = current->next;
}

void currentbac()
{
  if (current == first)
    cout << "This is the beginning of the list." << endl;
  else
    {
      list *previous;
      previous = first;
      while (previous->next != current)
        {
          previous = previous->next;
        }
      current = previous;
    }
}

void addbeginning()
{
  list *newlist;

  newlist = new list;
  cout << "Enter your name:" ;
  cin >> newlist->name;
  cout << "Enter your age:" ;
  cin >> newlist->age;
  cout << "Enter your height:" ;
  cin >> newlist->height;
  newlist->next=first;
  first=newlist;
}

void addending()
{
  list *newlist, *newlist2;

  newlist = new list;
  cout << "Enter your name: ";
  cin >> newlist->name;
  cout << "Enter your age : ";
  cin >> newlist->age;
  cout << "Enter your height : ";
  cin >> newlist->height;
  newlist->next = NULL;
  if (first == NULL)
    {
      first = newlist;
      current=first;
    }
  else
    {
      newlist2 = first;
      while (newlist2->next != NULL)
        {
          newlist2 = newlist2->next;
        }
      newlist2->next = newlist;
    }
}

void addmiddle()
{
  if ( current->next=NULL)
    addending();
  else
    {
      list *newlist;
      newlist=new list;
      cout << "Enter your name:" ;
      cin >> newlist->name;
      cout << "Enter your age:" ;
      cin >> newlist->age;
      cout << "Enter your height:" ;
      cin >> newlist->height;
      newlist->next=current->next;
      current->next=newlist;
    }
}

void deletebegin()
{
  list *newlist;
  newlist = first;
  first = first->next;
  delete newlist;
}

void deletemiddle()
{
  if ( current->next=NULL)
    cout<<"There is no one after this.";
  else
    {
      list *newlist;
      newlist=current;
      current=current->next;
      delete newlist;
    }
}

void deleteend()
{
  list *newlist, *newlist2;

  if (first == NULL)
    cout << "End of list" << endl;
  else
    {
      newlist = first;
      if (newlist->next == NULL)
        {
          delete newlist;
          first = NULL;
        }
      else
        {
          while (newlist->next != NULL)
            {
              newlist2 = newlist;
              newlist = newlist->next;
            }
          delete newlist;
          newlist2->next = NULL;
        }
    }
}

void display()
{
  list *newlist;

  newlist = first;
  cout << endl;
  do
    {
      if (newlist == NULL)
        cout << "End of List" << endl;
      else
        {
          cout << "Name is: " << newlist->name << " ";
          cout << "Age is: " << newlist->age << " ";
          cout << "Height is: " << newlist->height;
          cout<<" <-- Current position ";
          cout<< endl;
          newlist = newlist->next;
        }
    }
  while (newlist!=NULL);
  cout << "End of list" << endl;
}


int main()
{
  first = NULL;
  do
    {
      display();
      cout << endl;
      cout << "Choose an option: " << endl;
      cout << "1. Move the current position forward once." << endl;
      cout << "2. Move the current position backwards once." << endl;
      cout << "3. Add a member at the beginning of the list." << endl;
      cout << "4. Add a member at the current position of the list." << endl;
      cout << "5. Add a member at the ending of the list." << endl;
      cout << "6. Delete the first member from the list." << endl;
      cout << "7. Delete the member at current position from the list." << endl;
      cout << "8. Delete the last member from the list." << endl;
      cout << "9. End program." << endl;
      cout << endl << " >> " ;
      cin >> optn;
      switch (optn)
        {
        case 1 : currentfor();
          break;
        case 2 : currentbac();
          break;
        case 3 : addbeginning();
          break;
        case 4 : addmiddle();
          break;
        case 5 : addending();
          break;
        case 6 : deletebegin();
          break;
        case 7 : deletemiddle();
          break;
        case 8 : deleteend();
          break;
        }
    }
  while (optn!= 9);
}
```

I execute this program and number 3 works.But the others seem to crash my program :( 
can someone please show me the correct coding to this?
Im making a linked list with nodes filled with name height and age and it should work for any user.
And I m supposed to display the entire list right?Or dont linked lists appear that way ?
can some good soul please help?

Comment: where in this program does `current` get initialised?

Comment: For one thing, it looks like you never initialize current to NULL... so the first time the value of current is taken, it's likely to be some random garbage value.  Also, you don't ever check to see if current is non-NULL before dereferencing it.  Dereferencing a NULL or garbage pointer value will crash your program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I corrected your program and indicated all errors you should pay attention to in the comments. Please take a good look at them and try to see what you did wrong, so you can learn from this.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct list {
   char name[20];
   int age;
   double height;
   list *next;
};

list *first = NULL, *current = NULL; // Init current to NULL so you can test whether current is set at all

int optn = 0;

void currentfor() {
   if(current == NULL) {
      cout << "You don't have any members yet!" << endl;
   } else {
      if (current->next == NULL)
         cout << "This is the end of the list." << endl;
      else
         current = current->next;
   }
}

void currentbac() {
   if (current == first)
      cout << "This is the beginning of the list." << endl;
   else {
      list *previous;
      previous = first;
      while (previous->next != current) {
         previous = previous->next;
      }
      current = previous;
   }
}

void addbeginning() {
   list *newlist;

   newlist = new list;
   cout << "Enter your name:" ;
   cin >> newlist->name;
   cout << "Enter your age:" ;
   cin >> newlist->age;
   cout << "Enter your height:" ;
   cin >> newlist->height;
   newlist->next = first;
   first = newlist;

   if(current == NULL) // Set the current pointer to first, because this is the first element you add
      current = first;
}

void addending() {  
   list *newlist, *newlist2;

   newlist = new list;
   cout << "Enter your name: ";
   cin >> newlist->name;
   cout << "Enter your age : ";
   cin >> newlist->age;
   cout << "Enter your height : ";
   cin >> newlist->height;
   newlist->next = NULL;

   if (first == NULL) {
      first = newlist;
      current=first;
   } else {
      newlist2 = first;
      while (newlist2->next != NULL) {
         newlist2 = newlist2->next;
      }
      newlist2->next = newlist;
   }
}
void addmiddle() {
   if (current->next == NULL) // You were assigning here. Use == instead of = or you will assign NULL to
                              // current->next! Which is incorrect.
      addending();
   else {
      list *newlist;
      newlist = new list;
      cout << "Enter your name:" ;
      cin >> newlist->name;
      cout << "Enter your age:" ;
      cin >> newlist->age;
      cout << "Enter your height:" ;
      cin >> newlist->height;

      newlist->next = current->next;
      current->next = newlist;
   }
}

void deletebegin() {
   list *newlist;
   newlist = first;
   first = first->next;

   // You need to update the current pointer first
   if(newlist == current) {
      current = current->next;
   }

   delete newlist;
}

void deletemiddle() {
   list *newlist;
   newlist = first;

   // If we delete the first element
   if(current == first) {
      list *deleteMe = first;
      first = first->next;

      delete deleteMe;
      current = current->next;
   } else { // Otherwise
      // Search until newlist->next == current
      // Als test for newlist != NULL or you will try to get a next value from NULL -> crash!
      while(newlist != NULL && newlist->next != current)
         newlist = newlist->next;

      if(newlist != NULL) {
         delete newlist->next;
         newlist->next = current->next; // Also update the next from the previous node in the list! Or it will not disappear when displaying

         if (current->next == NULL) // You did it again here. Use == for comparing values instead of =
            current = first; // It doesn't mean that you don't have to delete if
         // you don't have a current->next. If you don't have a current->next,
         // just set it to first. The element does need to be deleted.
         else
            current = current->next;
      }
   }
}

void deleteend() {
   list *newlist, *newlist2;

   if (first == NULL)
      cout << "End of list" << endl;
   else {
      newlist = first;

      if (newlist->next == NULL) {
         delete newlist;
         first = NULL;
         current = NULL; // Current should also be null
      } else {
         while (newlist->next != NULL) {
            newlist2 = newlist;
            newlist = newlist->next;
         }

         delete newlist;
         newlist2->next = NULL;
         current = newlist2; // You forgot to update the current pointer.
      }
   }
}

void display() { 
   list *newlist;

   newlist = first;
   cout << endl;

   do {
      if (newlist == NULL)
         cout << "End of List" << endl;
      else
         {
            cout << "Name is: " << newlist->name << " ";
            cout << "Age is: " << newlist->age << " ";
            cout << "Height is: " << newlist->height;

            if(current == newlist) // You need to check whether you really are at the current position
               cout<<" <-- Current position ";

            cout<< endl;
            newlist = newlist->next;
         }
   }
   while(newlist!=NULL);

   if(newlist != NULL) // What if the newList was initially NULL? You will print twice.
      cout << "End of list" << endl;
}


int main(void) {
   first=NULL;

   do {
         display();
         cout << endl;
         cout << "Choose an option: " << endl;
         cout << "1. Move the current position forward once." << endl;
         cout << "2. Move the current position backwards once." << endl;
         cout << "3. Add a member at the beginning of the list." << endl;
         cout << "4. Add a member at the current position of the list." << endl;
         cout << "5. Add a member at the ending of the list." << endl;
         cout << "6. Delete the first member from the list." << endl;
         cout << "7. Delete the member at current position from the list." << endl;
         cout << "8. Delete the last member from the list." << endl;
         cout << "9. End program." << endl;
         cout << endl << " >> " ;
         cin >> optn;
         switch (optn) {
            case 1 : currentfor();
               break;
            case 2 : currentbac();
               break;
            case 3 : addbeginning();
               break;
            case 4 : addmiddle();
               break;
            case 5 : addending();
               break;
            case 6 : deletebegin();
               break;
            case 7 : deletemiddle();
               break;
            case 8 : deleteend();
               break;
            }
      }
   while (optn!= 9);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem I can see is that *current is not initialised to anything.

So option 1 will call `currentfor()`, and because `*current` is pointing to garbage, it will attempt to execute `current->next` which will cause an exception.

So I recommend initialising current to NULL:

```
list *first = NULL;
list *current = NULL;
```

and checking it in `currentfor` (and other such places):

```
void currentfor()
{
  if (current == NULL)
  {
    cout << "Current invalid" << endl;
    return;
  }
  if (current->next == NULL)
    cout << "List has ended!" << endl;
  else
    current = current->next;
}
```

Comment: so is it possible to check for just current using a single if without an else if?

Comment: You could use && to test both current, and current->next in the same if, but you are better off leaving it as above for a few reasons. 1. Better feedback / error messages. 2. Don't have to worry about the order of the clauses being optimised unpredictably (but in theory should always be the order it reads in, but that's a whole different discussion) 3. Easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

`current` is not initialized. Initialize it to `0` and test in the functions that access `*current`.