# Help with displaying list of contents C++ Linked lists!

Tags: c++

```
void display()


  {  

     list *newlist;

     newlist = first;

     cout << endl;

     do
      {
       if (newlist == NULL)
       cout << "List is empty" << endl;
       else
       {
          cout << "Name is: " << newlist->name << " ";
          cout << "Age is: " << newlist->age << " ";
          cout << "Height is: " << newlist->height;
          if (newlist==current)
          cout<<" <-- Current position ";
          cout<< endl;
          newlist = newlist->next;
       }
      }
    while(newlist!=NULL);
    cout << "End of List" << endl;
  }
```

I corrected my whole code with the help from here about the current initialization i love this site !
Just this one problem
I want to show the Cursor at the current node only.
But this code doesn't even show the "<--current position" written.
When I cut out the "if(newlist==current)"
the "<--current position" appeared for all the nodes.
So Im a bit confused as to where I should be placing this...
Also I have to insert a node between other nodes.
Can someone show me a code on how to show the "current position" wherever I move current or wherever the current is pointing at ?

Comment: You haven't shown your definition of `list`. Please, just use `std::list` which "just works" and gives you iterators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mahis, in your previous post I corrected your source code. Please read the comments in the code I provided. This will answer your question. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127500/c-programming-major-help-needed-linked-lists-i-just-cant-see-where-my-error-is/5127760#5127760).

You may have initialized your current to NULL, but when you add an element, you also need to set current to the correct value. For example, when you insert the first value in your linked list, current = first. The problem now is that you are comparing newlist to NULL, which will never evaluate to true. And so it will never print your current position.

Comment: I can't see that you changed the problematic code in your answer you link to. Now you may have fixed the root cause somewhere _else_ in that answer but you should probably make that clear - otherwise, this isn't really that useful an answer on its own.

Comment: The root cause was indeed somewhere else. I'll edit my answer then.

Answer (score 1):

That code should work fine, *if indeed `current` points to one of the nodes in the list.*

You should be able to find out by ineserting something like:

```
cout << newlist << " " << current << endl;
```

before:

```
newlist = newlist->next;
```

Comment: its showing garbage where i type newlist and current though.I've to show an arrow or something to point to the current node.